# Deployment WordPress on Heroku?

Tags: wordpress, heroku

I am Trying deployment WordPress on heroku that errorrs appear and I have issueswith  updating and installing plugins or themes should be done locally and then pushed to Heroku.and what about media (pictures and videos)

```
  remote:  !     WARNING: No 'composer.json' found!
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Your project only contains an 'index.php', no 'composer.json'.
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Using 'index.php' to declare app type as PHP is deprecated and
    remote:  !     may lead to unexpected behavior.
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Please consider updating your codebase to utilize Composer and
    remote:  !     modern dependency management in order to benefit from the latest
    remote:  !     PHP runtimes and improved application performance, as well as
    remote:  !     control over the PHP versions and extensions available.
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     For an introduction to dependency management with Composer and
    remote:  !     how to get the most out of PHP on Heroku, refer to the docs at
    remote:  !     https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md and
    remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php
    remote:
```

Answer (score 4):

For deploying any application CMS/FW based on PHP, you need to add `composer.json` at root as heroku default will run composer install.

So just add composer.json without any dependency at root ( same level as of wp-config ) then it will work perfectly

Comment: If you need to upload any image then upload on  S3 here is link for that

Answer (score 1):

There is a special repository for WordPress on Heroku.

https://github.com/php4dev/heroku-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

This [github repository](https://github.com/johnpbloch/wordpress) contains composer.json for Wordpress.